# Would fitting / filtering result in a loss of information?

Tags: fitting, filter

I have a very general (and probably also quite naive) question: Let's say I have arbitrary data points in `{x, y]`, when I plot all these and fit and/or filter them (with filter I mean something like a Chebyshev-filter, high pass and the like) and I use the fit or filter afterwards for further invesigations.
Would I risk to ignore data aka information?

Answer (score 5):

Information is lost after filtering.
In fact, that is one of the functions of filtering as a method: removing information that is not of interest.

For an extreme case, consider the filter function $F(X)=k$ with $k$ constant.
No information about $X$ remains after filtering

Comment: Is there a way to "preserve" information after filtering or is it apparently contradicting?

Comment: @Ben Trivially $F(X)=X$ preserves all information about $X$ (this an example of another extreme)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a rule of thumb or any other way to estimate how much information will be lost? Is it even quantifiable?

Comment: @Ben you can look at mutual information and other information-theoretic measures